# Need iPad Calendar library with similar look of default calendar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, calendar

I need to integrate calendar view for an iPad application. Is there any library available for iPad to integrate default calendar like view?

Please give some reference links for this.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Tapku Library, it has an iOS calendar. https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary

Comment: tapkulibrary is has ipad calender library or only iphone? any specific for iPad?